# Symfony 2 fatal error

Tags: php, symfony

I´m learning Symfony 2. I was doing this tutorial: [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html](http://kozusnikjan.com/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan) 
  [1](http://kozusnikjan.com/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan): http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html but I still have the same problem. After I made Hello Symfony Page, it shows me this:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Acme\HelloBundle\AcmeHelloBundle'
>   not found in
>   /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php
>   line 19

What to do with it?
[link](http://kozusnikjan.com/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan)

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the default AcmeHelloBundle? It seems like files are missing but `AppKernel` still tries to load them anyway.

Try either reverting AcmeHelloBundle files or removing bundle from `AppKernel`...

Comment: I was doing it as it is written in tutorial. I didn´t removed anything.

Comment: I tried to remove bundle from AppKernel but it only shows error about including or something like this

Comment: Ok, try running `app_dev.php` instead. What does it say? EDIT: I see that you've already changed link in you question to `app_dev` and that it works now :)

Comment: Now it works. Thank you for your answers. But I have other problem. I have webhosting with 2 aliases. If the URL is like this:
http://kozusnikjan.com/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/web/hello/Ahoj/fasdjkl
it works, but when URL is like this:
kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/web/hello/Ahoj/fasdjkl

it doesn´t. Where is the problem?